# Spawning asynchronous threads with timers in .NET web application

Tags: .net, asynchronous

Are there any dangers or problems with spawning an asynchronous thread that acts as a polling service but runs inside a .NET web application?

For example:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
    }

    private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do work
    }
}
```

Given that the application is running in its own application pool, are there any hidden implications that one should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Phil Haack has a good explanation of why this is a bad idea: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/

He has a NuGet package available that is a better alternative for running timers on a web server: http://www.nuget.org/packages/webbackgrounder